# Read lines between two specific words in a text document

Tags: r, regex

I have data of the form:

```
Trifle  
Beef gyoza with black vinegar dipping sauce  
8 Comments
```

And I want to extract the line between `Trifle` and `8 Comments`. Here it can be any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regmatches`

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bTrifle\\b.*\\n+\\K.*(?=\\n+.*8 Comments\\b)", x, perl=TRUE))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aJ2vW9/1)

For general cases.

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bTrifle\\b.*\\n+\\K.*(?=\\n+.*\\b\\d+\\h+Comments\\b)", x, perl=TRUE))
```

Comment: this `regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bTrifle\\b.*\\n+\\K.*(?=\\n+.*\\d+ Comments\\b)", x, perl=TRUE))`

Comment: How to do it for this case?
\n
0:25\n
To Prep\n 
Here I want to extract 0:25

Comment: care to post a link to somewhere we can learn to generalize this from, anyone? How is perl regex different?

Comment: If this is the test string -alt="mass |36 grams\nserving volume | 63 mL  (milliliters)\nserving density | 0.57 g\/cm^3  (grams per cubic centimeter)" title="mass | 36 grams..
Then how to extract 36 grams from this text?
It would be great if someone could share a link from where I can learn regex.

Comment: pls ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using `trimws` and the `(?s)` regex flag, which includes newlines in the set of characters covered by the dot:

```
pat <- "(?s)^.*Trifle(.+)8 Comments.*$"
trimws(gsub(pat, '\\1', x, perl=TRUE))
# [1] "Beef gyoza with black vinegar dipping sauce"
```